# Oracle SQL Pick the max record based on the condition from a column

Tags: sql, oracle

Sample Data: I need to pick the max Dept based on Team. The Match value from Rooms column should also have other rooms that have leading 00's

| ID | name | team | Rooms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1235 | MTAYLOR | Blue | ZQ123, ZQ456, ZQ654 |
| 3245 | MTAYLOR | Blue | ZQ123, 00254, 00859 |

With this I need to get the max ID based on Room number equals to ZQ123 but also contains leading Zero rooms
if no records in Rooms with leading 00's then choose ID with a match ZQ123 in Room Column to pick the max ID

Select ID, name, team max(ID)
where Rooms = 'ZQ123' and rooms contains leading 00's
if no rows with leading 00's in Rooms then choose ID with a match ZQ123

Results I need:

| ID | name | team | Rooms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3245 | MTAYLOR | Blue | ZQ123, 00254, 00859 |

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: I've read this slowly a couple times and am still having trouble following exactly what logic you are trying to implement. Maybe it's subtle enough that more sample data would help illustrate, try to capture as many scenarios as you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to want to use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function combined with a `CASE` expression to find the first row prioritise rows that have rooms beginning with `00` and then in order of descending `id` value:

```sql
SELECT id, name, team, rooms
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           ORDER BY CASE
                    WHEN ', ' || rooms LIKE '%, 00'
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 2
                    END,
                    id DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
  WHERE  ', ' || rooms || ', ' LIKE '%, ZQ123, %'
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name(ID, name, team, Rooms) AS
SELECT 1235, 'MTAYLOR', 'Blue', 'ZQ123, ZQ456, ZQ654' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3245, 'MTAYLOR', 'Blue', 'ZQ123, 00254, 00859' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | NAME | TEAM | ROOMS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3245 | MTAYLOR | Blue | ZQ123, 00254, 00859 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mib19PEG)

Comment: thank you this is helpful, have not thought of using the case statement within the Row_number.